# Are all normality-preserving homomorphisms/endomorphisms normal?

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups, normal-subgroups, group-homomorphism, simple-groups

This is **Exercise 4.9** of Roman's *"Fundamentals of Group Theory: An Advanced Approach"*. According to [this search](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=Are+Normality-preserving+homomorphisms+normal) and [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=Normality-preserving%2C%20homomorphism%2C%20normal&p=1), it is new to MSE.

### The Details:

From page 140 of Roman's book,

> **Definition:** Let $G$ be a group. A homomorphism $\sigma:G\to H$ is *normality-preserving* if $$N\unlhd G\implies \sigma N\unlhd H.$$

On the same page,

> **Definition:** An endomorphism $\sigma:G\to G$ of a group $G$ is *normal* if $\sigma$ commutes with all inner automorphisms $\gamma_g$ of $G$, that is, for any $a\in G$, $$\sigma(a^g)=(\sigma a)^g$$ for all $g\in G$.

*NB:* The latter is the only definition of a homomorphism being normal that I could find in the book so far.

### The Question:

> Are all normality-preserving homomorphisms normal? *Hint:* Use the fact that $S_3$ is simple.${}^{\dagger}$

*NB:* I think the question should be, "are all normality-preserving *endomorphisms* normal".

### Thoughts:

I suspect that the answer is "no" but I can't prove it yet. The group $S_3$ might be a counterexample.

I think I need to use the fact that $S_3$ is the smallest of the nonabelian groups.

The identity map ${\rm id}_{S_3}$ is normality-preserving trivially and normal.

The map

$$\begin{align}
\varphi :S_3 & \to S_3,\\
\tau &\mapsto e
\end{align}$$

is an endomorphism, and, since $\{e\}\unlhd \{e\}$, $\varphi$ is normality-preserving. It is also clearly normal.

Cheating a bit, the endomorphism monoid of $S_3$ has ten elements${}^{\dagger\dagger}$. They're given, I suppose, by their actions on the generators, so consider the presentation

$$S_3\cong\langle a,b\mid a^3, b^2, bab=a^{-1}\rangle\tag{1}$$

of $S_3$. I'm not sure what to do next (besides list all ways $a$ and $b$ can be mapped to elements in $S_3$; but surely there's a more sophisticated way than that, right?). Presentations aren't covered in the book so far too.

Please help :)

---

$\dagger$: But $S_3$ is not simple . . .

$\dagger\dagger$: See the Groupprops page "Endomorphism structure of symmetric group:S3". (I couldn't link to it because the address has a close-bracket.)

Comment: The "normal" definition only makes sense for endomorphisms. Now, prove that if  $\sigma\in End(G)$ is normal then for each  $g\in G$, $\sigma(g) g^{-1}\in Z(G)$.

Comment: The nontrivial non-identity endomorphisms of $G$ must kill all $3$-cycles, and the image of the two-cycles must be equal to each other. So you get three endomorphisms with non-trivial proper images, all of which are the subgroups of order $2$. But none of those maps is normal.

Comment: $S_3$ is not simple: $A_3$ is normal.

Comment: The smallest nonabelian simple group is $A_5$... surely you know that, and this was just a momentary lapse....

Comment: @MoisheKohan: Must it be central, or just centralize the image? I can get the latter easily, but I don’t see why the former holds when $\sigma$ is not an automorphism.

Comment: Ah, of course, @ArturoMagidin! I was thrown off by the hint given in the book. Thank you for pointing that out!

Comment: I think the hint is supposed to be “Use the fact that $S_3$ is centerless.”

Comment: @ArturoMagidin: Sorry, I meant centralize the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question as stated has an easy answer: “no”, because “normal” is a property of *endomorphisms*, and normality preserving morphisms need not be endomorphisms.

So presumably, the actual question should be: “Is every normality preserving **endomorphism** a normal morphism?”

As suggested by Moishe Kohan, let $\sigma$ be a normal endomorphism. Given $g\in G$, we know that $\sigma(a^g) = \sigma(a)^g$; i.e.,
$$\sigma(g)^{-1}\sigma(a)\sigma(g) = g^{-1}\sigma(a)g,$$
and therefore, that
$$(\sigma(g)g^{-1})^{-1}\sigma(a)(\sigma(g)g^{-1}) = \sigma(a).$$
Therefore, for every $g\in G$, $\sigma(g)g^{-1}\in C_G(\sigma(G))$; it centralizes the image of $\sigma$.

You can construct an example with an automorphism of $S_3$ (the nontrivial endomorphism that are not automorphisms have image of order $2$, so they are never normality-preserving). For instance, consider conjugation by $(12)$. This is normality preserving, but not normal: because $\sigma(13) = (12)(13)(12) = (123)$, and $\sigma(13)(13)^{-1} = (123)(13) = (23)\notin Z(S_3)$, so it is not normal.

P.S. My first counterexample was with $Q_8$, using the map $i\mapsto j\mapsto k\mapsto i$; I picked $Q_8$ because every subgroup is normal, so every endomorphism is normality preserving.